# What is the correct typescript type for the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just started with the TS .What class should I set for the onGetData in the interface. Because as I know, any cannot be left in the code

```
interface Props {
  onGetData: any;
}

class TSSS extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onGetData();
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default connect((dispatch: any) => ({
  onGetData: () => {
    dispatch(getUsersData());
  },
}))(TSSS);
```

Comment: Use a function type?

Comment: what is the function type?

Comment: I said **a** [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types), not *the* function type.

Comment: also `() => void` is a function type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use `: Function` as the type in interface so the code will be:

```
interface Props {
  onGetData: Function;
}

class TSSS extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onGetData();
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default connect((dispatch: any) => ({
  onGetData: () => {
    dispatch(getUsersData());
  },
}))(TSSS);
```

or, if you are using visual studio code, you can hover into your function `onGetData` to see what the type data of the function is, and select that copy and paste into your `interface Props` of `onGetData`